# Coldfusion form submission multiple fields with same name in CF8 & CF11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-11

I am getting different output when dumping results of a form submission with multiple fields with the  same name. In CF8 I got only first html element value in output result but in CF11 I got value as a list. Is this specific to server running in CF8 & CF11. Below is the prototype of  code I am using

```
<cfform method="post" action="">
    <select name="test">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="0">
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" />
</cfform>


<cfif structKeyExists(form,"btnsubmit")>
    <cfdump var="#form#">
</cfif>
```

In CF8 I got results as **'1'** but in CF11 I got result as **'1,0'**.

Please let me know if this is specific to my server upgrade. I just want to know that in CF8 server multiple fields with same name returns value as list or only returns value of first element.

Comment: Are you sure,that you have <input type="hidden" name="test" value="0"> in CF8 file also.

Comment: Um... standard HTML / HTTP protocol is that same-named form fields are *all* passed, and on the ColdFusion end of things this manifests as a comma delimited list of values. It's always been this way as far as I know (this stretches back to CF5).

Comment: Yes, <input type="hidden" name="test" value="0"> is also in CF8 file also. One thing I got interesting during testing is that when I put <input type="hidden" name="test" value="0"> before '<select>' element I got value as list when output form values in CF8 also. But it's not getting as list when I put hidden field after '<select>' . That's make me totally confused.

Comment: That is as designed. I m not sure about the version but I think in version 10, same name html elements were started being treated as a list. Which was not the case with CF8. I believe there is Raymond Camden's blog too about it.

Comment: @cfml_developer, the new feature introduced in CF10 was putting values of multiple same-named form fields into arrays (with a setting in Application.cfc). Putting the values in lists has been around for a long time, as others have pointed out.

Comment: I agree with Adam, as far as I can remember, multiple fields with the same name built a list of values, just as the checkbox field always has. If you could 100% guarantee your fields were never blank and never contained a comma, you could name all rows of a multi-insert form the same names and loop that way (Really unwise to do that, but just an example).

Comment: @Pradeep Try this code, just this `<cfif isDefined("form.gobtn")><cfdump var="#form#"></cfif><form action="#cgi.script_name#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="same" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="same" value="foo" />
<input type="text" name="same" value="banana" />
<input type="submit" name="gobtn" value="Submit" /></form>`. Try this on both CFs, you should get identical results.